# Does the 10 day counter reset for Unsung Hero after getting the Tenacious badge?

Tags: support, zero-score-badges

So I've been a SO member for a little over 1 month and in this time I have accumulated 14 zero-score accepted answers and 48 total accepted.  My most recent zero accept was 12 days ago and 2 days ago I got the Tenacious badge as expected.  But does the 10 day timer reset when getting that badge?

I thought I might have gotten both Tenacious and Unsung Hero at the same time?

14/48 > 25% 
14 > 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the timer does not reset, but you will generally get Tenacious some days earlier than Unsung Hero on account of the requirements being met earlier.

You've got at least [5 answers that are accepted with 0 votes but were in the last 10 days](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a836407%20isaccepted%3a1). You only currently surpass the 5 minimum as needed for Tenacious by the timestamps, not the full 10 you need for Unsung Hero.

Comment: Good point, I just now realize that I was sorting my answers by vote when counting, not by time...  I'm dumb, thanks for clearing this up for me!